# Callback arrow function returns undefined

Tags: javascript, react-native, ecmascript-6, callback, arrow-functions

This:

```
HeartbeatBridge.getInfo(8001, response => { return response })
```

returns: **undefined**

But this:

```
HeartbeatBridge.getInfo(8001, response => { console.log(response) })
```

returns **a value** in my log.

**Question:** Why the first line returns **undefined**? How can i get a value returned in the first line?

Comment: The second line doesn't return anything.  You are explicitly performing a console log as part of the callback logic.

Comment: You do not need the return keyword. `HeartbeatBridge.getInfo(8001, response => response)`